# what`s wrong with fstream operator << & operator >>?

Tags: c++

I need to serialize a int to local file and read it into memory. Here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain ( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    ofstream fileout;
    fileout.open ( "data,txt" );
    fileout << 99999999;
    fileout << 1;
    cout << fileout.tellp() << endl;
    fileout.flush();
    fileout.close();
    ifstream fileint;
    fileint.open ( "data,txt" );
    int i, a;    
    fileint >> i >> a;   //i != 99999999   a!= 1 WHY?
    cout << fileint.tellg() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work right, I can't get i==99999999  or a==1. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Are you sure the file name is `"data,txt"`? And you are not verifying that the operations work.

Comment: Look at the contents of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `operator <<` and `operator >>` are not duals -- `operator <<` outputs things directly with no padding or delimeters, while `operator >>` parses whitespace delimited input.  So you need to manually add whitespace delimiters between things in your output to have it read back properly.  You also can't output things that contain whitespace and expect to have them read back properly.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `fileout << 99999999 << ' ' << 1;` will work.